# for-else in python when for loop is not executed

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the best way for me to use for - else if I only want to go into else break when for loop is not executed? I want to raise Exception when x is 0. all i can think about is add one more if logic inside for loop any better way to do it?

```
x = 1
for i in range(1, x + 1):
    print(i)
    if i == x:
        break
else
    raise Exception
```

Comment: `if x== 0: raise Exception`?

Comment: `else` runs after the iterable is exhausted. if you break out of a `for` loop, the `else` won't run. Not sure why you would want to use an `else` like this

Comment: why `i==x` then break. anyways the loop will end when i will be equal to last value in range. break statement is an overkill

Comment: yap...so what I want is  exception get raise only when for loop is not executed

Comment: then check the value of x before entering the loop and raise exception. your question does not make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

I would separate that from the loop altogether. Test the condition first, *then* execute the loop:

```
if x <= 1:
    raise Exception

for i in range(1, x + 1):
    ...
```

Comment: I think this is what OP really wants.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag:

```
in_loop = False
for i in range(1, x + 1):
    in_loop = True
    print(i)

if not in_loop:
    raise Exception()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if/else` block to check the value of `x` before your loop

```
x = 1
if x == 0:
    raise Exception
else:
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        print(i)
        if i == x:
            break
```